# Advertisement in Loop Posts wordpress

Tags: php, loop, ads

I'm new here I want some help from you in terms of coding in wordpress. The point is that I want to make advertising between items as shown below:

[image]

```
<div class="row top-articles">
                <?php 

                        $args= array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>4,
                            'post__not_in'=> $excluded
                            );
                            $i=0;
                            $otherLoop = new WP_Query( $args );
                            while ($otherLoop -> have_posts() ) : $otherLoop->the_post();$i++;
                            $cat = get_the_category($post->ID)[0];
                            array_push($excluded,$post->ID);
                        ?>
<div class="small-6 top-story-container columns medium-6 large-3">
<article class="artikulli-<?php echo$cat->slug; ?> live">
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<div class="img-container">
<div class="inner">

<div class="gradient"></div>
<?php if($videos = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_videos','ecpt_foto', true)): ?>
<i class="icon dotie-icon_video dotie-icon_gallery phone-medium tablet-large desktop-medium"></i>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($foto = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_foto', true)): ?>
<i class="icon dotie-icon_gallery phone-medium tablet-large desktop-medium"></i>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('250x140'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article-meta equalise">
 <h3>
<span class="underline">

<?php if($live = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_live', true)): ?>
<span class="live">Live</span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 7 );?>
</span>
</h3>
<span class="datetime primary-color">
<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>
</span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</a>
</article>
</div>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WP_Query and then loop the results using break when you want to stop to put the ad.

```
$args = [                   
  'posts_per_page' => 5
];

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then loop 2

```
<section class="posts">
<?php $cont = 0; ?>
<?php
  while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); $cont++;        
    $id = get_the_ID();
    //Show your post here
    if($cont >= 1) break;
  endwhile;
  ?>
</section>

<div class="ad">
<?php //Show ad ?>
</div>

<?php //Rest of the posts ?>
<section class="posts">
<?php
  while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();     
    $id = get_the_ID();
    //Show your post here
  endwhile;
  ?>
</section>
```

If you are doing this in a Post or Page you should reset the query after showing the posts:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos full my code is top edit. You can do this in my code!?

Comment: Na ;D Just try to do it yourself and put the code in https://pastebin.com/ if you still can't get it...